# Laravel get relationship or all objects

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2. In my application, if a user is an admin, he can see all groups. Otherwise, he can only see his groups.

**Model**

```
public function groups() {
    if ($this->isAdmin()) {
        return \App\Group::get();
    }
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group');
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach($user->groups as $group) 
    {{ $group->name }}
@endforeach
```

**Result**

The code above works if the user is not an admin, but I get this error if the user is an admin

> Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

I tried this instead: `$user->groups() as $group`, it works when the user is an admin, but show nothing when it's not an admin.

**Question**

I know when I call a relation as a property (`$user->groups`), it returns a collection of objects. Instead, if I call it as a function (`$user->groups()`), I get a QueryBuilder instance.

What can I do to use the same syntax as in my view ?

**Note:** I cannot add all groups in the database to the admin, as admins must have no group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way is not using directly relationship for this but using extra method to handle this.

First in your model create simple relationship:

```
public function groups() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group');
}
```

and then create extra method:

```
public function availableGroups() 
{
    if ($this->isAdmin()) {
        return \App\Group::get();
    }
    return $this->groups;
}
```

Now in view you can use:

```
@foreach($user->availableGroups() as $group) 
    {{ $group->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I was already using an extra method, but I wrote the belongsToMany inline to simplify the code. I didn't know it's possible to call a relation as a property inside the model. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I've coded my own `Relation` class (Laravel 10, should be the same with previous versions), to fetch all models of a given type and still be able to chain the relationship with other Eloquent methods.

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RelateToAll extends Relation
{
  private $catchAll;
  private $ownerKey;

  public function __construct(Builder $query, Model $parent, $ownerKey, $catchAll = null)
  {
    /*
      It is possible to provide own callback to query all models.
      By default, it assumes that ID is numeric and is > 0
    */
    if (is_null($catchAll)) {
      $catchAll = function($query) use ($ownerKey) {
        $query->where($ownerKey, '>', 0);
      };
    }

    $this->related = $parent;
    $this->ownerKey = $ownerKey;
    $this->catchAll = $catchAll;

    parent::__construct($query, $parent);
  }

  public function addConstraints()
  {
    if (static::$constraints) {
      $query = $this->getRelationQuery();
      ($this->catchAll)($query);
    }
  }

  public function addEagerConstraints(array $models)
  {
    /*
      Warning! It is not possible to eager load this relation!
    */
    throw new \Exception("No eager loading for catch all relation!", 1);
  }

  public function initRelation(array $models, $relation)
  {
    foreach ($models as $model) {
      $model->setRelation($relation, $this->related->newCollection());
    }

    return $models;
  }

  public function match(array $models, Collection $results, $relation)
  {
    return $this->matchMany($models, $results, $relation);
  }

  public function getResults()
  {
    return $this->query->get();
  }
}
```

In addiction, a Trait for your Models:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Concerns;

trait CustomRelationships
{
  public function relatoToAll($related, $foreignKey = 'id')
  {
    $instance = $this->newRelatedInstance($related);
    return new \App\Helpers\RelateToAll($instance->newQuery(), $this, $foreignKey);
  }
}
```

to be used like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

use App\Models\Concerns\CustomRelationships;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
  use CustomRelationships;

  public function entities()
  {
    if ($this->role == 'admin') {
      return $this->relatoToAll(Entity::class);
    }
    else {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Entity::class);
    }
  }
}
```

More details, here: https://blog.madbob.org/laravel-catch-all-relationship/